# Apple Pay Stripe webpage use only displays in Safari Private mode?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

We implemented a stripe payment request button on a webpage and are not able to get it to display using normal safari on iPhone or mac. it will only show apple pay in private browsing!
Anyone have any idea or experience with this?

Webpage with issue:
https://easytab-staging.drinkeasy.us/easytab123/3

Stripe Documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button
All domains are verified

Comment: Apple Pay in Safari will always show up as working in private browsing (Apple Pay being enabled or disabled is one signal trackers use to fingerprint your browser configuration, which is why it's always enabled in private browsing mode). Do you see an Apple Pay button on the top of the following page?https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Comment: @JustinMichael yes I can see the apple pay button on normal safari session at that link

Comment: Can you confirm your Apple Pay domain shows up in the Dashboard as expected? https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payments/apple_pay

Comment: I have both below domains verified:
-drinkeasy.us  -easytab-staging.drinkeasy.us

Comment: It looks like your Apple Pay domains were added in test mode, not live mode. Apple Pay domains must be added in live mode to work.  See here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay

Comment: I moved page over to live account using the live stripe token and still hasn't worked. Stripe dev support has also not been able to explain what is going on. Also created a simpler page to try and get it working incase some other code we have is causing the issue: https://easytab-staging.drinkeasy.us/demo.html

Comment: The Apple Pay button shows up and appears to work for me on that page (although I did not complete the transaction).

Comment: I'm having this problem too (where Apple Pay only appears in Private Window). Did you solve it? I see 2 other people having the problem here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710164/apple-pay-button-not-show-in-stripe#comment131688514_71916450 I spoke with Stripe Dev Help, and the person there didn't know why this would happen.