# Apple pay button not show in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

Hi I am using iphone 6s safari browser but the payment-request-button not show (for website).

my all step are correct I used https server (ngrok).

also add my domain in the stripe apple pay certification.

using safari (Iphone 6s).

(On the other hand the when I excuted in the andriod chrome the google pay button show).

codding language (node.js)
using stripe server.

please help me I am stuck.

Comment: It is possible that Apple Pay isn't configured correctly on your iPhone. Easiest way to validate that is to go to this Stripe hosted page [1], If don't see an Apple Pay button that you can click on and make a test payment there, you should check if you wallet is configured correctly.
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for Apple Pay to show up on your phone, you have to have a card added to your Apple Wallet, otherwise it won't show up. Another way you can test if your code is working alright is if you check the site on Desktop Safari in a New Private Window.

Comment: yes if you have save card in your mobile make sure its working and also you you used sandbox id and make sure that applepay enable in your country

Comment: @Saint Apple pay shows up on my phone if i use provate mode but not in normal mode. Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: Worth noting, if automatic tax collection is turned on (automatic_tax [enabled]) in the API call, then the Apple Pay and Google Pay will not show up. Unless you add a shipping field and make it required. Source: https://stripe.com/docs/tax/faq#are-apple-pay-and-google-pay-available-to-use-with-stripe-tax

Comment: Worth noting, if automatic tax collection is turned on (automatic_tax [enabled]) in the API call, then the Apple Pay and Google Pay will not show up. Unless you add a shipping field and make it required. Source: https://stripe.com/docs/tax/faq#are-apple-pay-and-google-pay-available-to-use-with-stripe-tax

Comment: I'm having this problem too (where Apple Pay only appears in Private Window). Did you solve it? I see other people having the problem here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999543/apple-pay-stripe-webpage-use-only-displays-in-safari-private-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1 I spoke with Stripe Dev Help, and the person there didn't know why this would happen.

Comment: @Ryan This will happen if the user doesn't have a card added in Apple pay. It shows up in private mode as a button because if I remember correctly the browser doesn't check if there's a card added or not in this mode, so it just displays the button automatically. In regular non-private mode, the browser checks if there is a card added to the phone, and if not, apple pay doesn't display. I think the behavior is sorta weird too but that's how it goes afaik. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Saint Interesting. Thanks for your comment!